# How to keep state of View Controller A after switching to View Controller B?

Tags: ios, view, controller, push

I'm making an application in which I need the map of View Controller A to be in the same state after switching to View Controller B. However, I do not know how to switch the view to see the same state? Meaning when I switch back to View Controller A from View Controller B, I'm under the impression that I'm required to make a new instance of View Controller A, and then push that View Controller. However, this means that I lose all of my instance data from the first time it loads. How do I keep the data from the first time I'm in that view?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm under the impression that I'm required to make a new instance of View Controller A, and then push that View Controller.

Absolutely not. Assuming you're using a navigation controller, and you've pushed controller B, just pop it (`popViewController:` on the navigation controller) to return to the original instance of A.

Creating a new instance of A seems like a bad idea as it can lead to an infinitely high navigation stack.

If you're presenting modal view controllers, the principle is the same. `present...` puts B on top of A. `dismiss...` will remove B and take you back to your original A.

Comment: How do I "return to the original instance of A" is what I'm asking?

Comment: Using popViewController. Are you using a navigation controller? How are you moving from A to B in the first place? You mentioned pushing so I assume you're using a navigation controller.

Comment: I'm using "presentViewController" to present the new View Controller, and "dismissViewController" to dismiss the current one. What would be an example of some code that would get back to the original state?

Comment: Dismiss returns you to the previous view controller. I don't understand the problem you're having. Please can you add more detail to the question, including the code you're currently using?

Comment: "However, I do not know how to switch the view to see the same state? " @Jake Byman I suppose you should use delegate for resetting state of view controller A from view controller B before dismiss view controller B.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that when you move from one view controller to the next view, the new view does not get displayed until you have returned control back to IOS   (or you have exited the method).

example

presentviewcontroller …..

do something

return;      -> your new view controller only gets control after this statement
   }

so variables like 
     NSString *c = @"YES";
   will be gone but

```
properties such as 

  @property (nonatomic,strong)   *c;

will retain whatever value you have placed in it.
```

Is this your question ?

Comment: In case you are wondering where you are after dissmissviewcontroller you will be in a wait state waiting for response from the last view of the last controller. (waiting for a button to be pushed).